# Why is my SwiftUI WebKit not functioning properly when attempting to navigate back to the previous page?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, webview, webkit

I'm having a problem with the SwiftUi Webkit webview. I recently added goBack, reload, and go to another link with success. However, after adding loading functionality, my functionality buttons such as goBack and reload button have stopped working. I'm not sure why.

this is my code example:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isLoading = -1
    
    var webview : WebView {
        WebView(url: URL(string: "https://maxtvs.net/index.php")!, isLoading: $isLoading)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            Color(hex:0xff121722)
            VStack {
                webview
                HStack{
                    ForEach(0..<5){ index in
                        Spacer()
                        Image(["login", "reload", "home", "back", "exit"][index])
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                            .onTapGesture{
                            switch index{
                            case 0:
                               webview.loadURL(url: URL(string: "https://maxtvs.net/login.php")!)
                            case 1:
                               webview.reload()
                            case 2:
                               webview.loadURL(url: URL(string: "https://maxtvs.net")!)
                            case 3:
                               webview.goBack()
                            case 4:
                               exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
                            default:
                               print("error")
                            }
                            }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 8)
            }
            if isLoading == 1 {
               VStack(spacing: 12) {
                   ProgressView()
                       .foregroundColor(Color(hex: 0xff24D3FF))
                   Text("loading...")
                       .foregroundColor(.white)
               }
               .padding(16)
               .background(Color(hex:0xff26324b))
               .cornerRadius(12)
           }
            
        }
    }

}
```

```
struct WebView: NSViewRepresentable {

    let url: URL
    
    // -1 => initial
    // 0  => done
    // 1  => loading
     @Binding var isLoading: Int
    
    
    var webview: WKWebView = WKWebView()
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webview.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "fullScreenEnabled")
        webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webview.underPageBackgroundColor = NSColor(Color(hex: 0xff121722))
        webview.uiDelegate = context.coordinator
        webview.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webview
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ UpdatedWebView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if self.isLoading == -1 {
            UpdatedWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }
    
        
    func goBack() {
        webview.goBack();
    }
    
    func reload() {
        webview.reload()
    }
    
    func loadURL(url: URL) {
        self.webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
    
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {
        var parent: WebView
       
        init(parent: WebView) {
           self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!){
            self.parent.isLoading = 1;
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.parent.isLoading = 0;
        }
        
        func goBack() {
            self.parent.goBack();
        }
           
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runOpenPanelWith parameters: WKOpenPanelParameters, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: @escaping ([URL]?) -> Void) {
               
            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
            openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
            openPanel.allowedContentTypes = [.png, .image, .jpeg]
            openPanel.begin { result in
                if result == .OK {
                    completionHandler(openPanel.urls)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
extension Color {
    init(hex: UInt, alpha: Double = 1) {
        self.init(
            .sRGB,
            red: Double((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            green: Double((hex >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            blue: Double((hex >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
            opacity: alpha
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I expected it to operate normally, however after removing the isLoading state variable, the buttons started working again.